# When is uint8_t ≠ unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c, types, unsigned-char, uint8t

According to C and C++, `CHAR_BIT >= 8`.
But whenever `CHAR_BIT > 8`, `uint8_t` can't even be represented as 8 bits.
It must be larger, because `CHAR_BIT` is the minimum number of bits for any data type on the system.

On what kind of a system can `uint8_t` be legally defined to be a type other than `unsigned char`?

(If the answer is different for C and C++ then I'd like to know both.)

Comment: I wonder if it's legal to have a `char` with only 7 real bits and 1 padding bit.

Comment: @Mysticial: Nope, I think all `char`s must have all of their representation bits participate in determining their value.

Comment: Or maybe a 16-bit `uint8_t` where 8 is real and 8 is padding. I'd shoot whoever made such an environment though. :)

Comment: The C++ standard lists it as optional. `typedef signed integer type int8_t; // optional`

Comment: @Mysticial: Not sure that's allowed either, because the width is supposed to be exactly 8 bits. :P

Comment: @Mysticial: [u]int*_t is required by the standard to have no padding bits and to be twos-complement if signed.

Comment: @Mysticial: Wouldn't you lose range if that happened? Meaning, you need all 8 bits to represent some `char`.

Comment: @Mysticial: Such environments do exist (it's common for DSP architectures to be unable to address anything smaller than a word); in that case, `uint8_t` shouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uint8\_t vs unsigned char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725855/uint8-t-vs-unsigned-char)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If it exists, `uint8_t` must always have the same width as `unsigned char`. However, it need not be the same type; it may be a distinct extended integer type. It also need not have the same representation as `unsigned char`; for instance, the bits could be interpreted in the opposite order. This is a silly example, but it makes more sense for `int8_t`, where `signed char` might be ones complement or sign-magnitude while `int8_t` is required to be twos complement.

One further "advantage" of using a non-char extended integer type for `uint8_t` even on "normal" systems is C's aliasing rules. Character types are allowed to alias anything, which prevents the compiler from heavily optimizing functions that use both character pointers and pointers to other types, unless the `restrict` keyword has been applied well. However, even if `uint8_t` has the exact same size and representation as `unsigned char`, if the implementation made it a distinct, non-character type, the aliasing rules would not apply to it, and the compiler could assume that objects of types `uint8_t` and `int`, for example, can never alias.

Comment: If I'm to believe the snippet of draft standard posted in another answer, `uint8_t` must be defined as a typedef.

Comment: `typedef __uint8_t uint8_t;` is a typedef.

Comment: In the interest of humour, perhaps an implementation might decide to be consistent with it's naming conventions and, in contrast to `long long`, it might introduce a `short short`. Hence, `typedef short short int8_t;`...

Comment: In 2003 ± 2 (not going to go dig it up in the mail archives right now), the GCC team contemplated making `[u]int8_t` special extended integer types exactly so that it could be optimized more aggressively ... but eventually rejected the notion on the grounds that programmers are very likely to expect them to have the same special aliasing properties as `char`.  (This was around the same time we were getting screamed at by the kernel people for doing type-based alias analysis *at all*, so we were all a little skittish.)

Comment: @Zack: Thanks for the interesting historical note. It would be nice if gcc still provided those types, but didn't use them by default, so that a feature test macro or similar could switch to them, enabling the more aggressive optimization.

Comment: @Zack interesting, well this issue popped up in a [question today](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26299253/1708801) and I don't see a portable workaround, which is unfortunate. +1 btw.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Nice question. The trivial workaround, however, is to use the `restrict` keyword, or to copy the pointer to a local variable whose address is never taken so that the compiler does not need to worry about whether the `uint8_t` objects can alias it.

Comment: @R.. thank you for the suggestion, the OP posted a follow-up question and [stated that __restrict__ did not work in gcc for them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297571/how-to-create-an-uint8-t-array-that-does-not-undermine-strict-aliasing#comment41264766_26297914) but the other suggestion did.

Comment: Divorcing `uint8_t` from character types was actually discussed at the GCC bugzilla: see <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66110>.

Answer (score 33):

> On what kind of a system can `uint8_t` be legally defined to be a type other than `unsigned char`?

In summary, `uint8_t` can only be legally defined on systems where `CHAR_BIT` is 8. It's an addressable unit with exactly 8 value bits and no padding bits.

In detail, `CHAR_BIT` defines the width of the smallest addressable units, and `uint8_t` can't have padding bits; it can only exist when the smallest addressable unit is exactly 8 bits wide. Providing `CHAR_BIT` is 8, `uint8_t` can be defined by a type definition for any 8-bit unsigned integer type that has no padding bits.

---

Here's what the C11 standard draft (n1570.pdf) says:

> **5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types**
>   1   The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if
>       preprocessing directives. ... Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or
>       greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> ```
> -- number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
>    CHAR_BIT                                            8
> ```

Thus the smallest objects must contain exactly CHAR_BIT bits.

---

> **6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**
>
> ...
>
> 4 When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
>   char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
>   1. ...

Thus, those are (some of) the smallest addressable units. Obviously `int8_t` and `uint8_t` may also be considered smallest addressable units, providing they exist.

> **7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types**
>
> 1 The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width
>   N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus,
>   int8_t denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8
>   bits.
>
> 2 The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with
>   width N and no padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned
>   integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.
>
> 3 **These types are optional.** However, if an implementation provides
>   integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits,
>   and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement
>   representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

The emphasis on "**These types are optional**" is mine. I hope this was helpful :)

Comment: So what's the purpose of `uint8_t` if it's never different from `unsigned char`?

Comment: @Mehrdad I guess in the case of when you actually need a `int8` it would not compile at all when `CHAR_BIT > 8` since `int8_t` wouldn't even exist. Whereas if used `char` and `CHAR_BIT > 8`, then you might get a half-broken build.

Comment: @Mysticial: Weird, couldn't you already just say `#if CHAR_BIT > 8... #error ZOMG... #endif` if your program is supposed to not work for those systems?

Comment: It is different from `unsigned char`. `unsigned char` is guaranteed to exist, but is only guaranteed to be 8 bits when `CHAR_BIT == 8`. `uint8_t` isn't guaranteed to exist, but is guaranteed to be 8 bits when it does.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between `char` and `int8_t`, besides the width. A `char` might use ones' complement, two's complement or sign-and-magnitude representation, where a `int8_t` is required to use a two's complement representation.

Comment: I always thought the point of all the specific-size types was so that if something weird was going on, things either kept working or broke right away and told you so. They're also far more readable, when you're not working with `char`s.

Comment: It would also be good to say if `char` is guaranteed to have `CHAR_BIT` bits and quote the standard for that.

Comment: Hey, if you decide to delete you answers, do ping me so I can repost them and get rep haha But I have enough rep for job market now, I'm just doing this to save the world.  What I really want now is to make money.

Comment: @autistic I thought it was not possible to retract the CC BY-SA of one's answers. But you should chill, I'm just joking.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.

Comment: @autistic `char` can be `unsigned`, `int8_t` is signed.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 true. I can't edit that in to the comment, but let it be known that I meant to mention the possibility of `char` being an unsigned type.

Answer (score 8):

A possibility that no one has so far mentioned: if `CHAR_BIT==8` and unqualified `char` is unsigned, which it is in some ABIs, then `uint8_t` could be a typedef for `char` instead of `unsigned char`.  This matters at least insofar as it affects overload choice (and its evil twin, name mangling), i.e. if you were to have both `foo(char)` and `foo(unsigned char)` in scope, calling `foo` with an argument of type `uint8_t` would prefer `foo(char)` on such a system.

Comment: "However, it need not be the same type; it may be a distinct extended integer type." covers that in part, although it's true it might easily be overlooked.

Comment: @LucDanton `char` is not an *extended* integer type.

Comment: "it need not be the same type" is the relevant part. I took the rest to be an example.