# C Struct with uint8 array weird behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have problem with following C struct:

```
typedef struct AnchorPixel{
    int32 X;
    int32 Y;
    uint8 CH[5];
} AnchorPixel;
```

Actually, I have problem with CH array inside it. I just cannot manipulate CH array. For example, following program

```
AnchorPixel a;
a.CH[2] = 5;
cout << a.CH[2];
```

gives output:

```
♣
```

If I change CH type from uint8 to int32, problem disappears. This works:

```
typedef struct AnchorPixel{
        int32 X;
        int32 Y;
        int32 CH[5]; 
    } AnchorPixel;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [uint8_t is probably typedef'ed as a char](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26299253/1708801) ... I am guessing that is what `uint8` really is.

Comment: Also since I see `cout` I am guessing this should really be tagged C++

Comment: You are right Shafik Yaghmour

Comment: This works AnchorPixel a;
 a.CH[2] = 5;
 cout << (int32)a.CH[2];

Comment: Which comment and I right about? About tagging this C++ or about the typedef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that `uint8` is typedef'ed as a `unsigned char`, we [can see on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecbd31215cb3ad86) for `uint8_t` this is the case. The `cstdint` header includes `stdint.h` and there `uint8_t` is indeed a typedef to `unsigned char`:

```
typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
```

The output you are seeing is consistent with `cout` treating `a.CH[2]` as a `char` type,