# How to have a type which is like unsigned char, but not allowed to alias?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'd like to have a type, which is like `unsigned char`:

- sizeof is 1
- integer values can be assigned to it (without any casts)
- bit manipulations are allowed
- arithmetic is allowed, but not a must
- unsigned
- trivially copyable

But, unlike `unsigned char`, it is not allowed to alias. I mean, a type, which doesn't have the exception [[basic.lval/11.8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.8):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> [...]
>
> - a char, **unsigned char**, or std​::​byte type.

Is it possible to have a type like this?

The reason: I almost never use `unsigned char`'s aliasing property. So, I'd like to use a type instead, which doesn't prevent certain kind of optimizations (note, I asked this question because I actually have functions, which aren't optimized well, because of the aliasing-allowing property of `unsigned char`). So, I'd like to have a type for which this is true: "don't pay for what you don't use".

---

Here's an example, where `unsigned char` prevents optimization: [Using this pointer causes strange deoptimization in hot loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295216/using-this-pointer-causes-strange-deoptimization-in-hot-loop)

Comment: static_assert that std::uint8_t is available.

Comment: @RichardCritten `std::uint8_t` won't help much since most implementations typedef it to be `unsigned char`. // edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-%E2%89%A0-unsigned-char#comment23169800_16138470

Comment: Why does it matter so much that integer values can be assigned to it *without casts* that you'd edit the question in response to a solution that requires it? I can't think of a reason why writing `some_type{n}` instead of `n` is a dealbreaker

Comment: @Justin: "integer values can be assigned to it". For me, it already means `a = 42;`, with no casts. For your solution, it is not true, that "integer values can be assigned to it". You cast it, so you assign an enum, not an integer. I've edited the question to make this clear, not to discredit your answer.

Comment: You can use a couple of `#ifdef`'s and `restrict`, `__restrict` or `__restrict__`.

Comment: @geza: Are you using this for string manipulation or manipulating a sequence of 8-bit integers?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't have specific area in mind. It happened a lot of times before that aliasing behavior of `unsigned char` made my code slower. I'd like to have a type, which can be used in almost every situation instead of `unsigned char`. But I understand if this cannot be done. I've asked this question, because I'm not very much up-to-date with current C++ standard, maybe something has changed that makes this possible.

Answer (score 5):

That section of the standard calls out `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte`. However, you can make your own type which is like `std::byte` and it wouldn't be allowed to alias:

```
enum class my_byte : unsigned char {};
```

Using it isn't so nice, as you have to cast to `unsigned char` to do anything meaningful with it. However, you can overload the bitwise and arithmetic operators to make it nicer to work with.

---

We can verify this with the following simple function:

```
auto foo(A& a, B& b) {
    auto lhs = b;
    a = 42;
    auto rhs = b;
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

If `A` was allowed to alias with `B`, the compiler would have to generate two loads: one for `lhs` and one for `rhs`. If `A` was not allowed to alias with `B`, the compiler can generate a single load and just add the value to itself. [Let's test it](https://godbolt.org/z/XbJyoN):

```
// int& cannot alias with long&
auto foo(int& a, long& b) {
    auto lhs = b;
    a = 42;
    auto rhs = b;
    return lhs + rhs;
}

// std::byte& can alias with long&    
auto bar(std::byte& a, long& b) {
   auto lhs = b;
    a = (std::byte)42;
    auto rhs = b;
    return lhs + rhs;
}

// if my_byte& can alias with long&, there would have to be two loads
auto baz(my_byte& a, long& b) {
    auto lhs = b;
    a = (my_byte)42;
    auto rhs = b;
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

This results in the following:

```
foo(int&, long&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 42
        add     rax, rax
        ret
bar(std::byte&, long&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 42
        add     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        ret
baz(my_byte&, long&):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 42
        add     rax, rax
        ret
```

Thus `my_byte` does not inherit the same aliasing properties as `char` and `std::byte`

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this approach is that it doesn't support integer assignment conveniently (needs a cast), and I don't see any way to fix this.

Comment: @geza You can write `my_byte{n}`, making it look like any other type without implicit conversions.

Comment: I mean, I'd like to write `a = 42;`, just like I do for `unsigned char`. With no casts.

Comment: @geza I can't think of a way to make that work, and it really isn't a big deal. Lacking implicit conversions isn't much of a pain, especially since you don't have to write `static_cast<my_byte>(n)`.  Also, I think it's technically not considered a cast. You could add a literal for it like `42_byte`.

Comment: I intend to replace `unsigned char` with this hypothetical type in my code base. It would mean a lot of additional casts. It is noise, I don't like it.

Comment: Isn’t `std::byte` usually implemented exactly as an `enum class`?

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own type:

```
#include <type_traits>

class uchar {
    unsigned char value = {};

public:
    template <typename T,
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible_v<T, unsigned char>,
            int
        > = 0>
    constexpr uchar(T value)
        : value{static_cast<unsigned char>(value)}
    {}

    constexpr uchar()
    {}

    template <typename T,
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible_v<T, unsigned char>,
            int
        > = 0>
    constexpr uchar& operator=(T value)
    {
        this->value = static_cast<unsigned char>(value);
        return *this;
    }

    explicit constexpr operator unsigned char() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    friend constexpr uchar operator+(uchar lhs, uchar rhs) {
        return lhs.value + rhs.value;
    }

    friend constexpr uchar operator-(uchar lhs, uchar rhs) {
        return lhs.value - rhs.value;
    }

    // And so on...
};

// The compiler could technically add padding after the `value` member of
// `uchar`, so we `static_assert` to verify that it didn't. I can't imagine
// any sane implementation would do so for a single-member type like `uchar`
static_assert(sizeof(uchar) == sizeof(unsigned char));
static_assert(alignof(uchar) == alignof(unsigned char));
```

Comment: @Ivan That was on purpose. Note that the `operator unsigned char()` is `explicit`. You have to explicitly ask for it with `static_cast<unsigned char>(uchar())`. You could remove the `explicit` if you want an implicit conversion

Comment: Then `int() ? int() : uchar()` becomes broken.

Comment: @Ivan Which is why I don't recommend implicit conversions in both directions

Comment: Note that there is no way to guarantee that this type has the size/alignment of `unsigned char`. You can `static_assert` on it, but that's the best you can do.

Comment: @NicolBolas Very true. I would be very surprised if those `static_assert`s failed, however. I can't imagine any implementation would add padding to a single-member type.

Answer (score -1):

The aliasing rules of C++, including its "character type" exception, derive from those of C which were based on a couple of relatively non-controversial principles:

1. Given a construct like:

   ```
    int x;
    int test(double *p)
    {
      x=1;
      *p = 2.0;
      return x;
    }
   ```

   a compiler shouldn't be required to accommodate the possibility that `*p` might identify the same storage as `x`.
2. A construct like:

   ```
    void dump_hex(void *dat, int len)
    {
        unsigned char *p = (char*)dat;
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            printf("%02X", p[i]);
    }
   ```

   should be usable on any data type, and it should be possible to write code that operates on signed and unsigned data interchangeably.

Although the Standards don't mandate this, I think most people would agree that the intention is that on implementations where `char` is 8 bits,

```
    void dump_hex2(void *dat, int len)
    {
        uint8_t *p = (char*)dat;
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            printf("%02X", p[i]);
    }
```

should work just as well as the version with `unsigned char`.

The Standard would allow an implementation which was capable of supporting constructs that at least vaguely resembled `dump_hex2` above without having to pessimistically accommodate all scenarios related to each and every `uint8_t*` anywhere in the universe being able to identify part of each and every addressable object of every type, but unfortunately it does nothing to require that implementations make even the slightest effort to support such constructs.  Still, that's probably the closest one can come to a construct which will be compatible with existing implementations and yet allow implementations that seek to efficiently accommodate the tasks programmers need to perform to generate more efficient code than would otherwise be possible.