# Changing endianness or byte order within a union

Tags: c, unions

I am working on a project involving communications. I would like to be able to take a struct and typecast it into bytes in preparation for transmission.  Unfortunately, endianness is not working out for me.

The standard that I'm working with has the following definition:

```
uint8_t address;
uint8_t function;
uint8_t startAddressHi;
uint8_t startAddressLo;
uint8_t numberOfRegistersHi;
uint8_t numberOfRegistersLo;
```

It would be nice to be able to type cast to `uint8_t` and simply transmit the entire struct in one go, but the problem is that the `Hi` bytes of the `startAddress` and `numberOfRegisters` is at a lower index.  I am hoping that there is some little-known method of changing the byte order of the definition:

```
typedef union{

    struct rturxfields{
        /* header */
        uint8_t address;
        uint8_t function;

        /* data */
        uint16_t startAddress;   // <= needs some special sauce
        uint16_t numberOfRegisters;
    }RtuRxFields;

    struct rturxfieldbytes{
        /* header */
        uint8_t address;
        uint8_t function;

        /* data */
        uint8_t startAddressHi;
        uint8_t startAddressLo;
        uint8_t numberOfRegistersHi;
        uint8_t numberOfRegistersLo;
    }RtuRxFieldBytes;

    uint8_t array[RX_FRAME_LENGTH];
}RtuRxFrame;
```

Again, as defined, my union, the endianness is off.

I won't have access to `htons()` and similar from the networking library.  After doing more reading, I think I will simply get rid of the `RtuRxFields` struct and create utility functions `getStartAddress(RtuRxFrame* frame)` to retrieve the address cleanly.

Comment: This is a surprisingly hard problem. See [the related question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945121/dealing-with-data-serialization-without-violating-the-strict-aliasing-rule) on the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use `htons` and `ntohs` to convert the 16 bit values between host byte order (machine dependent) and network byte order (big endian).  When writing the 16 bit values, pass them through `htons` to put the bytes in the right order.

```
myunion.RtuRxFields.numberOfRegisters = htons(5);
```

If you don't have access to these functions, you can use bit shifting to get the high and low bytes and write them individually in the relevant fields:

```
uint16_t registers = 5;
...
myunion.RtuRxFieldBytes.numberOfRegistersHi = (registers >> 8) & 0xff;
myunion.RtuRxFieldBytes.numberOfRegistersLo = registers & 0xff;
```

Sending a struct over a network can be problematic due to structure padding.  Two different compilers on two different machines could make the same struct have different sizes on each.  See [this guide](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) for more details.

Comment: I should have added this to my post.  I'm writing this for a microcontroller and it does not have access to the network library.  I will add this information to my initial post and read through your reference.  Thank you!

Comment: @slightlynybbled See my edit.  You can use bit operations to extract the relevant bytes to write to the correct place.

Comment: is this something that can be done at compile time?  Your example appears to occur at run time.

Comment: @slightlynybbled Unless you plan on setting constant data, it has to be done at run time.  Bitwise operations are pretty cheap, so I would think using them wouldn't be a concern.

Comment: You are right, not a concern.  I was just hoping for something more elegant, thank you for your time!