# How to serialize data in C to send in a socket

Tags: c, sockets, serialization, struct, casting

I have to serialize some data and after send it using socket AF_UNIX.
I have read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577161/passing-a-structure-through-sockets-in-c)) that I can't create a struct and just send it using a cast (void *). So, I would like to know which is the best method to handle this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Check this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945121/dealing-with-data-serialization-without-violating-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: As long as sending and receiving system have the same endianness, encoding, and type widths, and your struct does not contain pointers, you can simply send its contents as is.

Comment: @thebusybee And the most important - struct padding

Comment: @EugeneSh. Correct. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1. Roll your own exactly as in the question you referenced.
2. Use an off-the-shelf serialization/deserialization system. If you go this route, Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) are pretty much industry standard. For constrained projects (embedded, etc.) [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) is a good choice for the implementation.