# how to convert 'const char *' to 'const unsigned char *'

Tags: c++, aes

how to convert 'const char *' to 'const unsigned char *'

```
 bool AES(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {  
     std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(Data), Size);
     AES_cbc_encrypt(s.c_str(), enc_out, Size, &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);
    }
```

the error got while compilation of the program

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char *' to 'const unsigned char *'
      for 1st argument
void AES_cbc_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
```

I tried this doesn't work

```
std::string s(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(Data), Size);
```

Comment: Why aren't you just passing `Data` to `AES_cbc_encrypt`?

Comment: `std::string` is `std::basic_string<char>`, so you probably need `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`, but anyway, why do you need temporary string object?

Comment: Awesome This work like a Cart @Sneftel

Comment: @myaut Is `basic_string<unsigned char>` guaranteed to exist though? As far as I remember the standard only requires `basic_string` specializations for `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`. I'll have to check.

Comment: @DeiDei: why not? `std::string` is not specialization but a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. You can miss some overloads for `std::hash` or `operator <<`, though

Comment: CHAR_BIT is at least 8 and char has to be the narrowest unit for a implementation. This means when `uint8_t` is available, it must be an alias to `unsigned char`. (If char is wider than 8 bit, them `uint8_t` won't be provided)

Comment: `std::vector` has more appropriate semantics for this than `std::basic_string`. Of course, in this case you don't need a container class at all, see the answer by @gurka.

Answer (score 1):

`uint8_t`, [if it's available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-%E2%89%A0-unsigned-char), is just a typedef to `unsigned char`. Therefore, you can just do:

```
 bool AES(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {  
     AES_cbc_encrypt(Data, enc_out, Size, &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);
 }
```

Note that you should probably return something in your function as well.

Comment: The OP *must* return something, or else it's undefined behaviour.