# Underlying type for std::uint8_t

Tags: c++, standard-library

**Question**:
Is there any c++ toolchain, where `std::uint8_t` exists, but is **not** a typedef for `unsigned char` (or `char`, if it is unsigned)?

EDIT: 
Conversely: Is such a thing even possible in a standards conforming implementation?

**Background / Motivation**:
I'm mainly asking because I want to know if `std::uint8_t*` can be used portably to access individual bytes (just like `unsigned char*`). And yes, I'm aware of `std::byte`, but thats not relevant here. I'm mainly interested in toolchains for x86, arm and mips, but out of curiosity I'd also like to hear about other examples.

Comment: There are some DSPs that just don't have octects - typically, they can only access memory in some bigger word size -, so you may have 16-bit `char` and no `uint8_t` at all. Edit: but re-reading your question  I see that you already excluded this case (you are requiring `uint8_t`).

Comment: This [twitter convo](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/822174071412510720) and [gcc bug report comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66110#c13)  may be helpful depending on context

Comment: Why would you not just use `unsigned char*` to portably access individual bytes?

Comment: @Brian: Because it is shorter ;). Mainly, because the project I'm working in does it that way.

Comment: Also - while still not ideal - I do think the name is better for talking about classig 8 bit bytes (I doubt it would be safe to use my code on a machine where `CHAR_BIT != 8`)

Comment: The answer to such a generic question is 'Yes'. Given there are about 8 billion ppl, everything which is physically possible, is likely to exist. :).

Comment: @SergeyA: you got me there. I wanted to add the adjective "relevant", but would have opened a whole different discussion ;)

Comment: I don't know of any such toolchain. (Should this be an answer or a comment?)

Comment: I think it's a safe practical assumption that if there ever was such a toolchain it would allow uint8_t to alias other types to avoid breaking existing code

Comment: @user2079303: l was asking about std::uint8_t.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16138237/3235496 is related to the second question. Making `uint8_t` a special extended integer type, so that it could be optimized more aggressively, is an idea that periodically pops up (I'm sure this was discussed by the GCC team many years ago)... eventually it's always rejected.

Comment: I think I misread part of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `char` is not an *unsigned integer type*, even if it is, in fact, unsigned. Since `uint8_t` must be a *unsigned integer type*, it never can be `char`.
2. `CHAR_BIT` must be at least 8, while the next smallest standard unsigned integer type, `unsigned short`, must have at least 16 bits. If `uint8_t` exists, then it must be "an unsigned integer type with width 8 and no padding bits." If `uint8_t` denotes a *standard unsigned integer type*, then it can only be `unsigned char`.
3. However, nothing in the wording prevents `uint8_t` from denoting an implementation-defined *extended unsigned integer type*. I don't know of any implementations that do this, however.