# Difference between uint8_t and unsigned char

Tags: c

I'm using mplabX 4.20, and xc8 compiler. I'm trying to understand which is the difference between uint8_t and unsigned char. Both of them have size from 0 till 255.
Both of can hold characters and numbers. But which is better to use, and for which case?

Example if i want to create a buffer for holding a string.

```
uint8_t buffer[20]="Hello World";
unsigned char buffer[20]="Hello World";
```

In most cases i need to hold characters. Which is the best practise for this action?

Comment: `uint8_t` is not a native data type; it is merely a `typedef` of `unsigned char`. But have a look at this! it might actually be a duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-%E2%89%A0-unsigned-char/16138308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using mplabX 4.20, and xc8 compiler. I'm trying to understand
>   which is the difference between uint8_t and unsigned char. Both of
>   them have size from 0 till 255. Both of can hold characters and
>   numbers. But which is better to use, and for which case?

`unsigned char` is the unsigned integer type corresponding to `signed char`.  Its representation does not use any padding bits.  Both of these occupy the same amount of storage as type `char`, which is *at least* 8 bits, but may be more.  The macro `CHAR_BIT` tells you how many it comprises in your implementation.  Every conforming C implementation provides all of these types.

`uint8_t`, if available, is an unsigned integer data type exactly 8 bits wide and with no padding bits.  On an implementation having `CHAR_BIT` defined as 8, this is the same type as `unsigned char`.  On such systems you may use the two types interchangeably wherever the declarations provided by `stdint.h` are in scope.  On other systems, `uint8_t` will not be declared at all.

> Example if i want to create a buffer for holding a string.

If you want to declare a buffer for holding a string then as a matter of style, you should use type `char`, not either of the other two:

```
char buffer[20] = "Hello World";
```

Although either of the other two, or `signed char`, can also be used for string data (provided in the case of `uint8_t` that the type is defined at all), type `char` is the conventional one to use for character data.  Witness, for example, that that's the type in terms of which all the `string.h` functions are declared.

You should use `uint8_t` where and only where you need an integer type with exactly its properties: unsigned, 8 value bits, no padding bits.

You should use `unsigned char` where you want the smallest unsigned integer type available, but you don't care whether it is exactly 8 bits wide, or where you want to emphasize that it is the same size as a `char` -- the smallest discrete unit of storage available.

You should use `signed char` where you want the smallest signed integer type available but don't care about the exact size or representation.

You should use `int8_t` where you want a signed integer type with exactly 7 value bits, one sign bit, and no padding bits, expressed in two's complement representation.

You should remain mindful that `uint8_t` and `int8_t` are not guaranteed to be available from every C implementation, and that where they are available, their use requires inclusion of `stdint.h`.  Furthermore, this header and these types were not part of C90 at all, so you should not use them if compatibility with legacy C implementations is important to you.

Answer (score 1):

> difference between uint8_t and unsigned char

If you're on a some exotic system where `CHAR_BIT > 8`, then `uint8_t` isn't going to be defined at all.

Otherwise (if `CHAR_BIT == 8`) there is no difference between `unsigned char` and `uint8_t`.

> i need to hold characters

Then use plain `char`.

Functions that operate in strings usually have [`const`]`char *` parameters, and you won't be able to pass your `unsigned char` arrays to them.