# Read uint8_t from std::stringstream as a numeric type

Tags: c++

My understanding is that reading a `uint8_t` from a `stringstream` is a problem because the `stringstream` will interpret the `uint8_t` as a `char`. I would like to know how I can read a `uint8_t` from a `stringstream` as a numeric type. For instance, the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint8_t ui;
    std::stringstream ss("46");
    ss >> ui;
    cout << unsigned(ui);
    return 0;
}
```

prints out `52`. I would like it to print out `46`.

EDIT: An alternative would to just read a `string` from the `stringstream` and then convert the solution to `uint8_t`, but this breaks the nice chaining properties. For example, in the actual code I have to write, I often need something like this:

```
   void foobar(std::istream & istream){
       uint8_t a,b,c;
       istream >> a >> b >> c;
       // TODO...
   }
```

Comment: Read two bytes and parse them via `std::stoi`?

Comment: That is the ugly solution. I am aware of it.

Comment: Eee, what exactly is ugly about it?

Comment: I was hoping that there was something equivalent to `unsigned(...)` that would perhaps return a reference to the original `uint8_t` that tells `stringstream` to just get 8 bits.

Comment: @freakish - Not the OP, but creating a string and parsing it ourselves instead of the stream (the thing whose job it is) seems off.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, apparently the stringstream class doesn't handle the case. So...

Comment: Your note does not make sense to me - you can read `uint16_t`, cast **from** it and never use it again... Of course, some range check and stream state invalidation with that too.

Comment: @freakish - Looks as much on the face of it. But even then I don't blame the OP for asking.

Comment: @LogicStuff: I worded that poorly. I am worried about range checking if I used a uint8_t. Removed that comment..

Comment: @bremen_matt a char is a char, in the string "46" the first char is '4' having the code 52, just read a _number_ for the compiler point of view

Comment: @bruno - But as `std::uint8_t` is advertised as a numeric type, not as a char, this is an issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller in that case gnu compiler / libs are wrong ?

Comment: @bremen_matt what is the version of your compiler ?

Comment: @bruno - Sounds like appeal to authority. That's shaky grounds to stands on. Even more so when even the [GNU team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-%E2%89%A0-unsigned-char#comment23169800_16138470) once considered aliasing something else for those types.

Comment: gcc version 7.3.0. But I tried on several versions.

Comment: @StoryTeller: `<rant>` another inconsistency of C++, caught between C compatibility and high level presentation `</rant>`. More seriously, the problem is that the `char` type is explicitely an integer type, but requires a special processing when IO is involved. The best I can imagine here would be a dedicated type holding a `uint8_t` and having specialized insertors and extractors and convertors to/from char.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Yeah, it's definitely a library issue, no doubt about it.

Comment: is sad but read an unsigned short/int then cast may be with range checking

Comment: Right. I can read off a uint16_t. That is what I was doing in the code.But it just adds a lot of code. I thought there would be some standard function for this. If there isn't then I will just accept it.

Comment: Is there a better/cleaner way of doing this (preferably with a tmp) than in the answer I posted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can overload the input `operator>>` for `uint8_t`, such as:

```
std::stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream& str, uint8_t& num) {
   uint16_t temp;
   str >> temp;
   /* constexpr */ auto max = std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max();
   num = std::min(temp, (uint16_t)max);
   if (temp > max) str.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
   return str;
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cVjLXJk11Gigf5QE

To say the truth I am not sure whether such a solution is problem-free. Someone more experienced might clarify.

---

**UPDATE**

Note that this solution is not generally applicable to `std::basic_istream` (as well as it's instance `std::istream`), since there is an overloaded `operator>>` for `unsigned char`: [[istream.extractors]](http://eel.is/c++draft/input.streams#istream.extractors). The behavior will then depend on how `uint8_t` is implemented.

Comment: This looks nice. If you put it in an anonymous namespace, then I imagine that any damage would be limited

Comment: And although I just asked about stringstreams, I guess you could easily change that `stringstream` to `istream`, and then are covered for all input streams.

Comment: @bremen_matt It doesn't seem to be so simple. Look here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8a2kGAywWyJUfPzr. The compiler obviously gives precedence to the _simple implicit conversion_ of `ui` to `char` before pairing `str` with `ss` by _derived-to-base_ conversion. Not sure how to solve this.

Comment: `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, uint8_t& num)`... Forget the template and `#include <istream>`

Comment: Btw, I had never heard of Wandbox. I love how you can switch the compiler like that...

Comment: @bremen_matt Yes, just then it will not cover _all input streams_. But you are likely fine with that.

Comment: @bremen_matt I like it so much for simple experiments. Especially because it supports Vim-like source editing, which I havne't seen in other online IDEs (like in popular IdeOne or Coliru).

Comment: `num = std::min(temp, (uint16_t)max);` – This has an implicit conversion, which is not so nice (and neither is the C-style cast). I will admit though that `num = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::min(temp, static_cast<uint16_t>(max)));` is not elegant either. Maybe move the assignment into the `if` rsp. a newly created `else` branch.

Comment: @DanielLangr "The compiler obviously gives precedence to the simple implicit conversion of `ui` to char." – This kind of implicit conversion does not apply to references. There is an `unsigned char &` overload for the `std::operator>>` for streams however. I'm not sure what causes the apparent ambiguity to be resolved in favor of the `std` version but highly suspect the following specialization in libstdc++: `extern template istream& operator>>(istream&, unsigned char&);` – It goes to show that it's a really bad idea to make ambiguous overloads of standard functions, I guess.

Comment: @ArneVogel Agree, I would better use only a version where no conversion is required in this case, such as the shown one for `std::stringstream`.

Comment: @ArneVogel Ooh, see your point now. I didn't mention the overloads for `unsigned char` before (http://eel.is/c++draft/input.streams#istream.extractors). This solution might be really fragile. I will put a note into the answer about it.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use `char` or `unsigned char`(uint8_t) if you want to read in a formatted way. Your example code and its result is an expected behavior.

As we can see from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

```cpp
template< class Traits >
basic_istream<char,Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<char,Traits>& st, unsigned char& ch );
```

This does "Performs character input operations".

`52` is an ascii code for '4'. Which means that the `stringstream` has read only one byte and still ready to read '6'.

So if you want work in the desired way, you should **use 2-byte or bigger integer types for `sstream::operator>>` then cast it to `uint8_t`** - the exact way that you self-answered.

Here's a reference for those overloads.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: I wouldn't really call this an "answer", but this is very very useful information.

Answer (score 2):

After much back and forth, the answer seems to be that there is no standard way of doing this. The options are to either read off the `uint8_t` as either a `uint16_t` or `std::string`, and then convert those values to `uint8_t`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint8_t ui;
    uint16_t tmp;
    std::stringstream ss("46");
    ss >> tmp;
    ui = static_cast<uint8_t>(tmp);
    cout << unsigned(ui);
    return 0;
}
```

However, such a solution disregards range checking. So you will need to implement that yourself if you need it.