# Does endianess matter when casting

Tags: c

Let's say I have an enum that only contains values up to 0xFF. I want to place that enum value into a byte variable. AFAIK enums are `int`s underneath (vxWorks). The machine I am coding for is big endian. I don't understand if this matters when I want to place it into a uint8_t. Which of these options will work and which is the best?

```
typedef enum {
  kEnum1 = 0x00,
  kEnum2 = 0x01,
  kEnum3 = 0xFF
} MyEnum;

MyEnum myenum = kEnum3;
uint8_t mybyte = 0;

// option 1, do nothing
mybyte = myenum ;

// option 2, explicit cast
mybyte = (uint8_t)myenum;

// option 3, use operators
mybyte = (myenum & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
```

When I test this on an online compiler, which I assume is little endian, option 3 of course does not work. But the others do. I just don't understand how big endian machines will treat these options.

Comment: A `enum` can by any integer type which has the range to hold all values. The compiler decides which type is used. Something like `unsigned char` is also possible and used on some platforms for `enum`'s with values in the range of `0xFF>=x>=0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cast converts a **value** to a new type. C 2018 6.5.4 5 says “Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the expression to the unqualified version of the named type…” So if an expression of enumeration type has value 255 (`0xFF`), then converting it to `uint8_t` produces the value 255 as a value of type `uint8_t`. This is true for any arithmetic value that is representable in the destination type. (If the value is not representable, then there can be various results, including wrapping, trapping, undefined behavior, and truncation, depending on the types involved.)

In more detail, C 2018 specifies the results of conversions between integer types in 6.3.1.3, and an enumeration type is an integer (C 2018 6.2.5 16: “An enumeration comprises a set of named integer constant values…”). 6.3.1.3 1 says “When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.”

The bytes used to represent an enumeration or other object are not relevant to casts, because the results of casts are specified by values, not representations.

Answer (score 0):

All of your examples will work the same regardless of endianness. That is, options 1 and 2 will work fine, and option 3 won't. You can fix option 3 like:

```
mybyte = myenum & 0xFF;
```

If you want one that *would* break, try this one, which actually addresses the underlying memory rather than using operators:

```
mybyte = *(uint8_t *)&myenum;
```

As far as which is the best, option 1 and 2 are 100% equivalent. If you want to be extra careful, just check that `myenum` isn't outside of the range of a `uint8_t` before doing the assignment.

Comment: This does assume that `uint8_t` is really a form of `char`, else `mybyte = *(uint8_t *)&myenum;` would be a strict aliasing violation.  [It doesn't have to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-%E2%89%A0-unsigned-char/16138308).

Comment: But on a big endian machine, wouldn't a 32 bit value of 255 be stored as `0xFF000000` where as on little it would be `0x000000FF`? So therefore byte operations would be different?

Comment: No, operators work on values, not representations.

Comment: Then why does it matter what way I pack a `uint16_t` into two `uint8_t`s? On big endian I need to go `byte1 = (short & 0xFF00) >> 8;` and `byte2 = short & 0x00FF`. This would be opposite for little...

Comment: Nope. It doesn't matter. The representation in memory might be different, but the operators extract the right values in both cases.