# Is uint8_t* equivalent to unsigned char* if uint8_t exists?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, uint8t

If `uint8_t` exist, is a pointer to `uint8_t` equivalent to a pointer to `unsigned char`? Means it can be used to access any object and does not cause UB when accessing a different object. I know that this rules:

```
int intVar=0;
unsigned char *charPtr=&intVar; //completely valid and does not cause UB
printf("%X ",*charPtr); //this is also valid and does not cause UB

struct SomeStruct_T structVar={};
int *intPtr=&structVar; //This causes UB
```

But what about this:

```
int intVar=0;
uint8_t *uint8Ptr=&intVar; //Is this valid?
printf("%X ",*uint8Ptr);   //If yes, is this also valid?
```

GCC with `-Wincompatible-pointer-types` warns about `unsigned char *charPtr=&intVar;` and `uint8_t *uint8Ptr=&intVar;`, but with a cast this warning goes away. This does not answer the question.
There is probably no system where `uint8_t *` will be different from `unsigned char *` but what does the standard say?

This question is about the pointer type which points to `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, not about the data type `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` itself. There are some fundamental properties of `unsigned char *` that may or may not apply to `uint8_t *`, such as being able to access any object, that are not relevant for the type `unsigned char` itself. This question is therefore not a duplicate of the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-%E2%89%A0-unsigned-char). The linked question is also about C++, but i don't ask about C++, my question is about C. Please do not mark this question as duplicate of the linked question, because the question is definitely not the same.

Comment: seems a dupe of [When is uint8\_t ≠ unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-%e2%89%a0-unsigned-char)

Comment: I think `int *intPtr=&structVar; //This causes UB` is fine as long (not UB) as you don't dereference it (I would need to dig up the standard to know for certain).

Comment: @underscore_d The linked question is about the data type, not the pointer type.

Comment: @underscore_d Please read both questions before you mark a duplicate, thank you. The other question is about `uint8_t` vs `unsigned char` not `uint8_t *` vs `unsigned char *` and the linked question is about C++ this question is about C.

Comment: I can read fine, thank you. C++ just inherits these types from C, and the behaviour/validity of the pointers is based on the types they point to, so it seems a clear dupe to me. Clearly the other user who voted to close as a duplicate also agreed, so I can't be the only one.

Comment: @underscore_d But you didn't. There are a lot of questions that are falsely marked as duplucate, so don't make an appeal to popularity fallacy. There are special characteristics of `unsigned char *` that are not directly related to `unsinged char` such as that you can access any object with `unsigned char *`. Marking it as duplicate of the linked question just shows you didn't understand or read the question or you don't know C well enough.

Comment: What? It's `unsigned char*` (and `char*`, and `std::byte*`) that has the special properties. Therefore, `uint8_t*` will only have said props iff `uint8_t` is a typedef to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @underscore_d This question is about C, not C++, `std::byte*` is not valid C code. The linked question does not say `uint8_t` has to be a typedef of `unsigned char` in C (there are comments say it could be in C++, but then again, this question is about C). If it has to be it would answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Proof:

The standard asserts that `sizeof(unsigned char)` is `1`.

The standard asserts there are no fractional sizes.

The standard does not allow `uint8_t` to have padding bits.

The standard does not allow `unsigned char` to have padding bits.

Therefore:

You can't have two `unsigned char`s in an `uint_8` by pigeonhole principle.

The size of `uint_8` must be 1.

Therefore blitting `unsigned char` through `uint8_t` or `uint8_t` through `unsigned char` is defined.

However, your code isn't completely valid because you took an endian dependency when you casted the pointer to int to a pointer to `unsigned char`. In C, pointer casts are transitive except when casting to or from a function pointer to a non-function-pointer so we may analyze as though you cast directly from `int *` to `unsigned char *`.*

<sup>*This is only true of casts. Blitting through a union or memcpy can defy this.</sup>

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be that a system has a native data with of 16 bit and 128 KiB RAM. The `char *` and `void *` pointer would need 2 words (2*16 bit) on such a system. Maybe the compiler puts all possible `uint8_t` variables, including stack and heap, in the lower 64 KiB so a `uint8_t *` pointer only needs 1 word and not 2 and making `uint8_t *` not able to accessing everything.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: You forgot about `malloc()`. The runtime can't possibly make this optimization because it doesn't know that `malloc()` is allocating uint8_t or not.

Comment: I said _including stack and heap_. And please keep in mind that there are systems without `malloc()`. A freestanding environment does not need to provide `malloc()`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 What about 6.3.2.3/7: "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned <sup>68)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
original pointer."? Surely `unsigned char` and `uint8_t` have the same alignment, so the pointer values convertible both ways?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 if `CHAR_BITS > 8` then no `uint8_t`

Comment: @0___________ Yes? We all know that, but how is that relevant?