# Why in g++ std::intmax_t is not a __int128_t?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, integer, standards

My question is pretty simple: as `std::intmax_t` is defined as the `maximum width integer type` according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), why it does not correspond to `__int128_t` in GCC?

Comment: As that's implementation defined you'd have to ask the GCC developer list, but I would imagine it's because the platform does not support 128bit ints natively.

Comment: I would guess it's because __int128_t is not a standard type (it's not listed at your link anyway).

Comment: language_lawyer, anyone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this is a violation of the C and C++ standards -- either that, or gcc doesn't consider `__int128_t` to be an integer type.

The C standard (both the 1999 and 2011 editions) doesn't require `intmax_t` to be one of the standard types; it's required to be "a signed integer type capable of representing any value of any signed integer type". In particular, it can be an *extended integer type* -- and if there is a 128-bit extended integer type, then `intmax_t` must be at least 128 bits wide.

The C standard even suggests using implementation-defined keywords that "have the form of an identifier reserved for any use" as the names of extended integer types -- such as `__int128_t`.

The 2011 C++ standard adopts C99's extended integer types feature, and defers to the 1999 C standard for the definition of `intmax_t` and `<stdint.h>`.

So if `__int128_t` is an *integer type* within the meaning defined by the standard (which it certainly *can* be), and is, as the name implies, 128 bits wide, then `intmax_t` must be at least 128 bits wide.

As [Stephen Canon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21265561/827263), changing `intmax_t` does require some work. The C and C++ standards do not recognize that as a justification for defining `intmax_t` incorrectly.

Of course all of this applies equally to `uintmax_t`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    __uint128_t huge = UINTMAX_MAX;
    huge ++;
    if (huge > UINTMAX_MAX) {
        puts("This should not happen");
    }
}
```

On my system (Linux x86_64, gcc 4.7.2), the above program prints:

```
This should not happen
```

If gcc conforms to the standard, then that should be possible only if `__int128_t` is not an integer type -- but quoting the [gcc 4.8.2 manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) (emphasis added):

> As an extension the **integer scalar type** `__int128` is supported for
>   targets which have an integer mode wide enough to hold 128 bits.
>   Simply write `__int128` for a signed 128-bit integer, or `unsigned __int128`
>   for an unsigned 128-bit integer. There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer
>   constant of type `__int128` for targets with
>   `long long` integer less than 128 bits wide.

I suppose one could argue that the "as an extension" phrase lets gcc off the hook here, justifying the existence of `__int128_t` under section 4 paragraph 6 of the standard:

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional
>   library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any
>   strictly conforming program.

rather than under section 6.2.6 paragraph 4:

> There may also be implementation-defined *extended signed integer
>   types*.

(I personally think that making `intmax_t` at least as wide as `__int128_t`, if it exists, would be more in keeping with the *intent* of the standard, even if it's (barely) possible to argue that it doesn't violate the *letter* of the standard.)

Comment: An especially determined language lawyer might argue that the notion of “extended integer type” is never formally defined by the standard; so long as GCC doesn’t say that `__int128_t` is such a type, and so long as they don’t interpret literals as having that type, there is no standard violation.  A more reasonable pragmatist might argue that a compiler should warn that you are using an extension, but support the type anyway as it is genuinely useful.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Thus the caveat: "either that, or gcc doesn't consider `__int128_t` to be an integer type". Still, I think that making `intmax_t` a typedef for `__int128_t` would be more in the spirit (as well as the letter) of the standard than making `intmax_t` smaller than `__int128_t`.

Comment: Agreed.  However, that turns out to require support from a decent number of components outside of a compiler, which are extremely resistant to any API breaking change.  While not impossible it is quite unlikely to happen anytime soon; supporting `__int128_t` as a not-quite-conformant extension is a reasonable compromise.  (I would argue that it should produce an error under `-std=c11`, and a compatibility warning under `-std=gnu11` or equivalent).

Comment: @StephenCanon: I've updated my answer; see the last few paragraphs.

Comment: pity but [GCC does not support any extended integer types.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html)

Answer (score 15):

Changing `intmax_t` requires not only changes to a compiler but also to numerous standard library functions that need to accept `intmax_t` arguments (and platform ABIs may define `intmax_t` as well).  A compiler can unilaterally provide `__int128_t` as an extension, but it cannot unilaterally change the type `intmax_t`.  That requires support from all of the standard library implementations that the compiler targets.

Comment: And the psABI for the architecture, which is not going to change in such an incompatible way for a rarely-useful purpose.

Comment: As an addition, also the preprocessing phase has to take that into account. It is supposed to decode constants of that type and to have all its expressions evaluated in `[u]intmax_t`.

Comment: I happened upon an article by C standard's project editor on this topic. C++, unlike C, has enough operator overloading facilities to circumvent the ABI issue, but obviously having std::intmax_t be different from intmax_t is weird and surprising. https://thephd.dev/intmax_t-hell-c++-c

Answer (score 5):

__int128 is not sufficiently functional to be used as an intmax_t

The stdint.h header must include a define INTMAX_C(9999999999999999999999)
This define lets you enter a constant into the C source for any value up to the maximum size of the type.

The GCC documentation says "There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type __int128 for targets with  long long integer less than 128 bits wide."

Therefore, it cannot be used for intmax_t.

Comment: The Standard requires these macros to be constant expressions, not literals.  So `#define INTMAX_MAX (((intmax_t)LONGLONG_MAX) << 64) | ULONGLONG_MAX)` seems acceptable.

Comment: The constant expressions must be suitable for `#if` expressions so no casts are allowed. Also this technique would not help with `INTMAX_C` which needs to be able to cope with any integer (within range) the programmer might wish to use.