# Variable template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Just want to confirm that type of templated variable can be independent of template. This compiles by g++:

```
template<class T> 
constexpr long MAX_AS_LONG = static_cast<long>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
```

Does it confirm to the standard?

(In all the examples on the internet, type of templated variable is `T` itself).

Comment: Yep, it's allowed. Will you take our word for it or do you want a quote from the standard?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't impugn knowledge of cats!

Comment: Bear in mind, those examples from the internet are typically focused on proving that the template produces different variables. So varying the type is just an easy way to prove it.

Comment: I hope it's not the actual fragment from your code. Cause it can very easily overflow with a T like size_t.

Comment: ...especially on Windows, where `long` is 32 bits.

Comment: you should rather ask something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417113/biggest-integer-datatype-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement the type of a template variable differs based on template arguments.

A common example is `std::is_same_v<T,U>` which is always a `bool`.